# How to create an attribute which will be persisted in all ActiveRecords (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add an attribute, which will be persisted in my database, to all my models classes in a Ruby on Rails project. I want something just like the created_ad and updated_at attributes, but I don't know how this is possible, or even if it is.

Do I have to add the attribute and column manually to all my models, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Good question.   Here's a reference to the ActiveRecord page that describes the variables you're talking about:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions for those wanting to understand the behavior he's referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to run a migration (or several) that will add the column to all needed models. No way around this.

As for how to go about the migrations: you are limited only by your imagination. The simplest way is to simply write out all migrations manually, a migration per table.

You also could write a script that will generate the migration files for you. Or do it all in the same migration: just call `add_column` in a loop.

Comment: I tend to agree with Sergio here.  I understand what it is you want to do, but you may just have to create the new columns yourself via Migrations.  There probably is some way to extend the base ActiveRecord behavior to do what you want, but in the end it might be more complicated than just adding the new columns yourself.

Comment: @TimHolt: to be honest, I don't see how any amount of tinkering with AR internals would help achieve persistence of new attributes. Something _has_ to create the columns in the actual database.

Comment: agreed.  It's sort of theoretically the right way to extend AR, but it would be a lot of work.

That said, it sounds like a great idea for a gem!

Answer (score 1):

For an existing project there is no way around generating the migrations for each model. You could possibly write a rake task to automate this by looping through the files in `app/models` and using a heuristic based  on the rails naming conventions to generate migrations.

```
names = Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '*.rb')).map do |p|
  Pathname.new(p).basename.to_s.chomp('.rb')
end.reject {|p| p == "application_record"}
models = names.map { |n| n.classify.constantize }
models.each do |m|
  next unless m.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  puts %x{ rails g migration add_foo_to_#{m.table_name} foo:string }
end
```

This is a (very) simplified example that does not take "namespaced" models into account or handle errors.

For a greenfield project or new models you can [create your own generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) which would add the additional column when you run the standard rails generator commands such as `rails g model`.

Comment: Not all models necessarily have a corresponding database table, there can be tableless models.

Comment: @ZohaibA.Butt: skipping non-AR models is a matter of adding a single conditional here. But good to be aware of this, yes.

Comment: @ZohaibA.Butt this is an extremely simplified example for brevity. For any real world application you would need to add error handling and look up the ancestors to make sure they are ActiveRecord models.

Comment: An alternative way to do this that would work at least on postgres is to use `SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname='public';` to get the names of each table and then generate a migration for each.

Comment: @max: mysql can do this style of introspection equally well. `select * from information_schema.tables where database = 'mydb'` or something like that.